# Could not find default endpoint element that references contract on live environment

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

When I run my page from a live environment I get error:

> "Could not find default endpoint element that references contract ".

When I run from my dev system using VS 2013 MVC the issue does not occur. I'm using the same API call. What is causing this issues to only occur in the live environment?

error:

> err:Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'FileName.IFileName' in the ServiceModel client configuration section.
>   This might be because no configuration file was found for your
>   application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract
>   could be found in the client element.

Comment: Would be helpful to see the configuration for your services.

Comment: Just going out on a limb... Are both prod and dev pointing to the same endpoint? Do you happen to be pointing to localhost? Is the service deployed to the prod environment? Is this a Silverlight application (your reference config could be hidden there)?

Comment: config, please, we need to see you config files (as in client and service)! :-)

Comment: Both are pointing to same endpoint. I have verified by looking at the web.config file. I'm not sure of any other way to check.

both are not pointing to localhost. Service is deployed to dev environment.

Comment: <system.serviceModel>
    <client xdt:Transform="Replace">
     
<endpoint address="http://servername.computer.com:8902/PageName" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPageName" contract="PageNameMyFile.IPageName" name="BasicHttpBinding_IPageName" />

   
 </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>

Answer (score 0):

The sample you've posted is a config transform rather than an actual config file, so there is still some ambiguity here. However, *if* this is the only client configuration you have:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="servername.computer.com:8902/PageName" 
          binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPageName" 
          contract="PageNameMyFile.IPageName" 
          name="BasicHttpBinding_IPageName" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

then the problem is pretty straightforward: there is no endpoint definition that references the contract `FileName.IFileName` - this configuration example only contains an endpoint that references `PageNameMyFile.IPageName`.